# Setting the delegate for UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I’m updating my code for the new `UIAlertController` and since there are a lot of alerts throughout the project, I pulled the alert code into its own class. `UIAlertController` works perfectly, but I am having trouble getting the old `UIAlertView` to work.

If I use *self* as the delegate, the code crashes. I suspect because the object is gone by the time the delegate is called. If I use `self.navigationController`, the code doesn’t crash but the delegate doesn’t get the button click. I have the same delegate method in the calling class and it doesn’t get called either.

I tried making the showAlert method a class method, but that didn’t work. I suspect I may need to set the `UIAlertView` delegate to the calling class, but have no idea how to do that.

```
@implementation ShowSystemAlert
- (instancetype)initWithNavigatioController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                   withManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
                            withScoreKeeper:(ScoreKeeper *)scoreKeeper
                               withWordList:(WordList *)wordlist {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _navigationController = navigationController;
        _mObjContext = context;
        _scoreKeeper = scoreKeeper;
        _wordList = wordlist;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)showAlert {

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {

        // code for UIAlertController goes here

        [self.navigationController presentViewController:alert animated:true completion:nil];

    } else {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"'Only Show Favorites'\nTurned Off"
                                                    message:@"aWe looked for words in the categories you selected but did not find any. We turned off 'Only Show Favorites' and found some words."
                                                   self.navigationController
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Settings"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];

        [alert show];
    }
}

#pragma mark - No Words

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"In alertView delegate");
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel buttonpressed on no words");
        PrefsTableViewController *ptvc = [[PrefsTableViewController alloc]
                                          initWithWordList:self.wordList];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:ptvc animated:YES];

    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I think you diagnosed the problem correctly. The problem is most likely that the instance gets deallocated before the delegate methods are called. When you create the `ShowSystemAlert` instance, assign it to a strong variable of the viewController so it won't be deallocated.

Comment: the code you posted would yield a syntax error, as the method call is illegal.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, that did it. One of those instances where, now that I know the answer, I wonder why I spent all day looking at the problem when the solution is so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface ShowSystemAlert:UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> // The delegate needs to be added to the class that will listen to the delegate. Generally the viewController.

// In your method where you create your alertView assign the delegate
alert.delegate = self;
```

Comment: This isn't right is it? I'm pretty certain that `UIAlertViewDelegate` needs to go on the interface like `@interface ShowSystemAlert <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

Comment: Sorry about that popeye. Long ass day and yes this needs to be in the @interface.

Answer (score 0):

Under iOS8, please change your delegate method `clickedButtonAtIndex` to `didDismissWithButtonIndex`

change this line to

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

with this

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
```

You should find this will solve the crash.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but it didn’t work. Mathias’ suggestion did it.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. the dismissWithButton solved a similar issue for me before, thought this might have been the same. Cheers